# change td width when hovering on react-table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-table

I use react-table package to set up my table component based on react-table example [reac-table, full-width-resizable-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/full-width-resizable-table). I add the css

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis
```

so when I resize, cell text is not overflow. my question is how can I write the css so when I hovering the `td`, width of `td` change back to full width so text can be fully display?
I have tried

```
.td:hover{
width: auto;
}
```

but it does not work
my codesandbox
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-keller-8snk8?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to `transform :scale()`

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

> The transform CSS property lets you rotate, scale, skew, or translate
> an element. It modifies the coordinate space of the CSS visual
> formatting model.

```
.th:hover,
.td:hover {
  background-size:  100% 100%;
  transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
  transform-origin:center;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

An example:

```css
th:hover,
td:hover {
  background-size:  100% 100%;
  transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
  transform-origin:center;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to increase `width` of table, then the near columns will be increased too. But if you want, you can try:

```css
   td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: chocolate;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 300px;
  /* max-width: 100px; */
}
```

```html
  <table>
<tr>
  <td>Some text</td>
  <td>Icon1 Icon 2 Icon3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Some text</td>
  <td>Icon1 Icon 2 Icon3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Some text</td>
  <td>Icon1 Icon 2 Icon3</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: no, it does not work. after hovering only text change size not all column width

Comment: @jacobcan118 please, see my updated answer

Comment: no..it does not work neither. as the width does not change at all